# Reading barcode with a Bluetooth barcode scanner on iOS App in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, barcode-scanner

I'm building an App for iPad (in Swift) that allow the user to read qr/barcode with an external reader connected via Bluetooth.

As a very first implementation, I put on view an hidden `UITextField` and make it `firstResponder`. The problem with this implementation is that I can't hide the keyboard and I can't find a way to achive this. The keyoboard is displayed in a minimal mode, but is not enough, I need to completely remove it from the screen.

My goal is: reading barcode from the external reader without show the keyboard on screen.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800488/how-to-hide-the-keyboard-assistant-bar ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
textField.inputView = UIView()
textField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
```